# CSS transform issue with an image swap and border radius simultaneously

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to find a solution for a slight issue that I'm having with some CSS. 
The goal is to switch from a square solid colored box, with centered text, to a circular image.
While what I have currently works, albeit clunkily I'm sure, the fact that both the colored div and the image end up the same size, means that there is a faint colored line surrounding the image. Is there a way to remedy this?
I thought I could scale the colored div at the same time, but it ends up scaling both.

```
<head>

<style>

.images-container{
position: relative;
width: 175px;
height: 175px;
margin-top: -191px;
}
.images-container > img{
display: block;
width: 175px;
height: 175px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
}

.images-container > img:nth-child(1){ 
filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
opacity: 1;
z-index: 0;
}
.images-container > img:nth-child(2){ 
filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
opacity: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
.images-container:hover > img:nth-child(1){ 
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
z-index: 0;
border-radius:50%
}
.images-container:hover > img:nth-child(2){ 
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
z-index: 3;
border-radius:50%;

}
.textbg{
background: #007049;
    position: relative;
width: 175px;
height: 175px;
 transition:all 1s;
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s;

}
.textbg:hover {
border-radius:50%;
}
.imgtransition{
 transition:all 1s;
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s;
margin-top:-191;
}
.textalign {
    color:#fff;
    line-height: 175px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="textbg">
    <p class="textalign">Family</p>
    <div class="images-container"><img class="imgtransition" src=
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/16x16.png">
    <img class="imgtransition" src=
    "http://image1.masterfile.com/em_t/06/50/52/623-06505245er.jpg"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzk3Lf1r/)

Comment: I may have answered my own question...

I added :
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
to the textbg:hover class

example here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/q94tkzyh/)

I figure there is a more efficient way to do this still and would appreciate feedback

Answer (score 0):

Hi there add background transparent on your textbg hover

example:

```
   .textbg:hover {
    border-radius:50%;
        background:transparent;
    }
```

Hope it works.